# DDEBS repository looking in wrong path on Zesty 1704, sources.list.d modifications not correcting path

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I am trying to configure Cuckoo Sandbox to use a Ubuntu guest VM. Currently, it appears version 2.0.6.2 only supports Ubuntu 17 guests (18 has not bee working lately).

The installation guide calls for the ddeb debug repositories to be enabled on the machine.

### My Problem

Ubuntu keeps looking in http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists.old/dists/zesty...

Ubuntu should be looking in http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists.old/

### What I've tried

My sources.list.d/ddebs.list looks like:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists.old zesty main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists.old zesty-updates main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists.old zesty-proposed main restricted multiverse universe
```

I got the same behaviour when removing the `dists.old` (still looks for dists/zesty).

I know Zesty is EOL, but it appears to be the only supported option for this use case. It will be airgapped after installation, so being intentionally vulnerable wouldn't be the worst.

Comment: To clarify further, it is looking for the release file. However, apt appends `/dists/zesty` to the end, which obviously does not exist on the repo

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  Ubuntu 17.04 was released 2017-April (thus 17.04) with 9 months of support reaching EOL on 13-Jan-2018. Being EOL it's off-topic here unless question is specific to moving to a supported release. Many sources are removed after a release reaches EOL so sources that did exist during its support life tend to disappear post-EOL (to reduce storage costs for hosters). (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up manually pulling the package from launchpadlibrarian (a/k/a librarian.launchpad.net) and confirming the hash. Doesn't appear to be a way to override the default APT behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line in your `sources.list.d/ddebs.list`:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com ../dists.old/zesty main restricted multiverse universe
```